# wget with big data file straight to s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wget

I'm using wget to pipe straight from a [www.backblaze.com](http://www.backblaze.com) url to S3 with the following command:

```
> wget -qO- '<url>' | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket>/{data_file}
```

The  is to a file, which can be anywhere from 10 to 20Gb in size. I've ran the process a couple of times with a Python script with the following:

```
os.system('wget -qO- '<url>' | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket>/{data_file}')
```

When the process is complete I don't receive any errors, however the files in my s3 bucket are only ~4 or 5Gb in size, suggesting the entire file wasn't either read or written to the pipe.

I'm not sure what the problem is here. Has anyone had experience using wget to pipe big data files?

Comment: Does it work correctly when you run it from the shell instead of from python?

Comment: Yes, but I need to run it through Python

Comment: We understand that. But demonstrating that it works *outside* of python confirms that the problem is probably not with your network, or with `wget` or the `aws` command, which narrows down the possible problems. Honestly, we usually ask these questions for a good reason.

Comment: Amazon S3 never adds partial objects. If the resulting S3 object does not contain the correct and complete data then it is because your client did not send the correct data (which probably indicates that the read failed somehow).

Comment: PS the lack of visibility into the failure here is exactly why you don't shell out of Python to run scripts using os.system(). That said, tweak your command line so that it emits errors to a file that you can review afterwards, and consider using its verbose option.

Answer (score 0):

```
os.system('wget -qO- '<url>' | aws s3 cp - s3://<bucket>/{data_file}')
```

Please note that there is general movement in `python` from using `os.system` to using `subprocess` built-in module. [`os` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) claims that `os.system`

> This is implemented by calling the Standard C function `system()`, and
> has the same limitations.

I am not *Standard C function `system()`-ninja* so I am unable to say if there is *do not use `|`* ramfication from above, but anyway I would suggest replacing `os.system` using `subprocess` built-in module, which seems to be general movement among `python` developers. See [Replacing shell pipeline in `subprocess` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) for example of piping.